# Xfce4 breaks down on every restart

Tags: linux, xorg, kali-linux, xfce, xfce4

I have casually been using Kali for quite a while, however just today I encountered this an issue, right after I swapped my Grub background image and restarted. Whenever I use my account, Xfce breaks down, I cannot see the window title, controls, border, nothing. Only two processes start by default, a terminal emulator and thunar. My Xfce panel too shows up, however the desktop is completely unusable and doesn't even react to right clicks. I managed to get it running numerous times by clearing the user config files, logging in and out of root, but after that all, anytime I reboot, or shutdown and start, Xfce, for my account anyways just glitches out. Is there any known solution to this problem?

Comment: Since you have a terminal emulator, what happens if you manually try to start the missing components from it? (Those being xfwm4 for the window decorations and xfdesktop for the desktop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very sorry for the late response. I managed to fix my problem.
Turns out, I had a sudo thunar instance running under my user. When XFCE tried to restore the session, it would restore thunar, but without privileges, which would cause it to simply "break down". The solution was to delete XFCE cache.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following fix successfully in Kali and in Ubuntu:

> sudo apt-get --fix-missing update (to get missing updates).
>
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  (to install new dependencies)
>
> When complete, run the sequence:
>
> sudo apt-get update  upgrade and autoremove

Restart after this and if the issue can be fixed, the above steps will fix it.  I have tested this.